# text not aligning properly in scrollview android

Tags: android, xml

i have a scroll view showing certain device information, but it looks like **[this](http://s24.postimg.org/kh9ykj911/piic.jpg)** after setting a DrawableLeft . how do i fix this behaviour? when i remove the drawable, the list looks well formatted. any help will be appreciated

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff" >

    <!-- action bar -->

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/actionbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#0080FF" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageButton1"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView5"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_font" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_return" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:onClick="shareapp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_share" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <!-- action bar -->

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/actionbar"
        android:background="@drawable/antivirus_bg"
        android:padding="10dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/ipip"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_device_info"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="ip"
                android:textColor="#084B8A"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/macmac"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_device_info"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="mac"
                android:textColor="#084B8A"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/macmac2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_device_info"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="mac2"
                android:textColor="#084B8A"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/ssid"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_device_info"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="ssid"
                android:textColor="#084B8A"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/pubip"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_device_info"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="ip2"
                android:textColor="#084B8A"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/unique_id_text_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_device_info"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="extra"
                android:textColor="#084B8A"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use an imageview with specify with and height instead of drawableLeft. Because drawableLeft or drawableRight will get drawable with real with and height of image.

You can remake layout as below:

```
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            >
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="32dp"
                android:layout_height="32dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/ipip"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="ip"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:textColor="#084B8A"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
```